# Wand inside Django: wand contains no images `MagickWand-1'

Tags: python, django, imagemagick, wand

I have fully working code that saves the first page of an PDF document to an image file, it works inside my virtualenv by executing it directly from commandline, but it throws error if I execute the same code inside a django project.

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='/hard_coded_path_to_file.pdf[0]', resolution=120) as img:
    img.save(filename="temp.jpg")


wand contains no images `MagickWand-1' @ error/magick-image.c/MagickWriteImage/13164
```

I'm on El Capitan, done brew install both `imagemagick` and `ghostscript`.

Comment: Have you solved your issue? Looks exact like mine, already trying to make it work for 2 days...

Comment: @Compadre Yes. It's Pycharm's problem, some env context is lost when ``runserver`` inside the pycharm. Resolved if you run it in terminal app. Of course, make sure you had done ``brew install ghostscript``

Comment: Already found :) but anyway thank you!

Comment: @Compadre  how do you resolve the pycharm issue?

Comment: @flooie you should add `PATH` variable with value `/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to environment variables in run configuration like this - [example](http://imgur.com/a/UjEyi)